# W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed. on pre-Lollipop

Tags: android, android-support-library, toolbar, compatibility, android-appcompat

When I try to press a Toolbar button on pre-Lollipop, it does not respond and I get this log output:

`07-20 16:31:59.797 25217-25217/io.github.delta.justreadit W/InputEventReceiver: Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.`

Everything is good on Android Nougat. I use Android support library v26.

### read.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/changeFontFamily"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_fontoptions"
        android:title="@string/view_settings"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
</menu>
```

### onOptionsItemSelected and onCreateOptionsMenu

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.read, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.changeFontFamily:
            fontOptionsMenuWindow.showAsDropDown(findViewById(R.id.changeFontFamily));
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't there. The problem was because of different view measuring algorithm on pre-Lollipop and Lollipop. I've used `ViewTreeObserver` to set the PopupWindow's size because i didn't know that `PopupWindow.setHeight` supports `WRAP_CONTENT`. Fixed.